# Simulate click on link with jquery

Tags: jquery, click

I want to simulate a click on a link using javascript but it doesn't work. 
The target is _blank, so it will open in other chrome tab (window.open() doesn't have the exatly same behaviour).

```
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="openLink()" />
<a href="./mypage.html" target="_blank" id="linkId">my link</a>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function openLink(){
        var link = $("#linkId");
        link.click();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function openLink() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.open($("#linkId").attr('href'), '_blank');
    });
}
```

Doesn't 'click' the link but simulates the same behaviour - as far as I know what you describe isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

change your method into this.

```
   <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">

    function openLink(){
        var link = $("#linkId");
        window.open(link.attr('href'), link.attr('target') != null ? link.attr('target') : '_self');
    }
</script>
```

this will handle same as its clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var link = $("#linkId");
        link.click();
});
```

Comment: `.click()` triggers the `onclick` event. It does not trigger the default behaviour of a link, ie following the link.